# Print arrays in each corresponding element

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've been trying to get this simple thing done.

I basically have this:

```
<div>
<p class="stars"></p>
</div>
<div> 
<p class="stars"></p>
</div>
```

Then I have an array with the following:

```
var arr = [4,5];
```

What needs to happen next is: First p element gets 4, the second one gets 5, and so on (if there's more in the array).

I know it should be done with jQuery.each(), though I can't seem to separate arrays in individual variables and then print them on each corresponding p element.

**Edit:**
// Based on the accepted solution below, I was able to add the following:

```
$('p').each(function() {
var numbr = parseFloat($(this).text());
var rstar = Array(numbr+1).join("★");
$(this).text(rstar);
});
```

How would I go about combining these two functions into one?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c73pjrrv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.each()` function to iterate over p elements and use iteration index i to access relevant element from array and set it as text:

```
$('p').text(function(i,o){
  return arr[i];
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ps7gh89g/)**

Also, the fiddle to the second (edit part) of the question:
http://jsfiddle.net/gfyvL0uj/

Comment: Thanks Milind! I was able to get going with your code and print out a few dynamic stars. I have edited my initial question with additional code. Is it possible to combine both functions into one?

Comment: can you create fiddle??

Comment: Here's the working fiddle >> both functions are in, trying to combine them into one for efficiency http://jsfiddle.net/c73pjrrv/

Comment: @OctoberEleven: can you post it as different question?? as it points to different issue than first problem??

Comment: @OctoberEleven: glad it helps :)